# SVN How to Get A List Of Files and Last Modified

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

First Question so please forgive if there's a simple answer.

I know I can use `svn ls URL-OF-REPO > file.txt` to get a list of files at URL location. 
I'm looking to get the last modified time of each these files printed alongside the list of filenames.

Is there a way of doing this? For example:

```
Filename        DateModified
File1           04/Sept/2014 17:55
File2           03/Sept/2014 16:50
File3           02/Sept/2014 15:45
```

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark it as answered to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the verbose flag on the `list` command:

```
svn list -v URL
```

This gives:

```
>svn list -v http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/svn/
1620332 stsp                  Aug 25 10:55 ./
1543507 julianfo         3866 Nov 19  2013 add-cmd.c
1573701 stsp            12898 Mar 03  2014 auth-cmd.c
1543477 julianfo        14770 Nov 19  2013 blame-cmd.c
1547517 philip           4388 Dec 03  2013 cat-cmd.c
1543507 julianfo         5645 Nov 19  2013 changelist-cmd.c
1140729 julianfo         5448 Jun 28  2011 checkout-cmd.c
1619777 stsp            17601 Aug 22 08:18 cl-conflicts.c
1618906 stsp             2264 Aug 19 13:26 cl-conflicts.h
1555135 rhuijben         3345 Jan 03  2014 cl-log.h
1618906 stsp            34594 Aug 19 13:26 cl.h
...
```

Columns are:

- revision
- last author to commit the file
- size in bytes
- modified date, as "MMM dd HH:mm", or "MMM dd yyyy" for dates more than 6 months prior it seems
- file name